# NSArrayController setFetchPredicate

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, nspredicate, nsarraycontroller

I have a simple `CoreData` application which stores information, names, dates, etc... and all is working. There is a search method, which uses the `setFetchPredicate` on an `NSArrayController` and the results appear in a table - this is working.

Looking at adding some addition code at the end of this method, so just before the method ends, I added a simple line to get the count of the NSArrayController.

```
  [searchArrayController setFetchPredicate: searchPredicate];

  [searchArrayController rearrangeObjects];

  NSlog(@"Count = %lu", (unassigned long)[[searchArrayController arrangedObjects] count]);
```

Results: Count = 1200

(1200 is the number of objects in the database.)

The table displays correctly, i.e. show the correct number of data objects, however the `NSLog` count is the entire database.

I placed a second `NSLog` in the beginning of the method. If I run the search a second time, the second `NSLog` shows the correct number of objects.

```
  Beginning method:
  NSlog(@"A-Count = %lu", (unassigned long)[[searchArrayController arrangedObjects] count]);
  ...

  [searchArrayController setFetchPredicate: searchPredicate];

  [searchArrayController rearrangeObjects];

  NSlog(@"B-Count = %lu", (unassigned long)[[searchArrayController arrangedObjects] count]);
  end of method
```

Results:

First Run:

A-Count = 1200

B-Count = 1200

`NSTable` displays correct number of objects

Second Run:

A-Count = 4 (This is correct for the search parameters)

B-Count = 4

It appears the first time though the method the NSArrayController has not yet been filtered based on the predicate when the B-Count `NSLog` is called. But this is at the end of the method, the NSArrayController should be filtered at this point.

I've got to be missing something simple here - any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rearrangeObjects` uses `filterPredicate`. `fetch` uses `fetchPredicate` but `fetch` is deferred until the next iteration of the runloop.

Comment: That was it, needed to use filterPredicate not fetchPredicate - thanks.